# Communication between two iPhones

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

What is the fastest way to communicate between iPhones? I can get it to work with CoreBluetooth, using BTLE, but is there a way to transfer data faster, perhaps using regular Bluetooth rather than Bluetooth LE? I don't want to rely on Wifi, but I would like to be able to send data faster.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bluetooth works for shorter distance. Check with this http://nshipster.com/multipeer-connectivity/ it will help you in what you are looking for.

Comment: BLE is designed for transferring data in a very limited size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Anand said in the comments, the **Multipeer Connectivity framework** is the way to go here! It handles all ios device to ios device communication using whatever networks are available, be it Bluetooth or WiFi.

http://nshipster.com/multipeer-connectivity/